# Decorate method to have the signature of a different method

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following classes:

```
class A(object):

    @classmethod
    def result(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def square(cls, **kwargs):
        r = cls.result(**kwargs)
        return r ** 2    

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def result(cls):
        return 2

class C(A):

    @classmethod
    def result(cls, *, x, y):
        return x + y
```

The method `square` in class A does not know about the implementation of `result` yet, hence gets generic `**kwargs` to accept anything and pass it on to `result`.

I would like to wrap `square` in a way that it takes the function signature of `result` of the child implementation. Hence, when I inspect

```
inspect.getfullargspec(C.square)
inspect.getfullargspec(C.result)
# both return FullArgSpec(args=['cls'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['x', 'y'], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

What would be the nicest way to do this?

`functools.wraps` is doing this for the name and the doc, but not for the signature. `boltons.funcutils.wraps` does this for name, doc and signature. I want to do it for signature, but not name and doc. Also, in my particular use-case, the methods are class methods.

**EDIT:**

I have gotten a wrapper to work for both classes and instances, with `boltons.funcutils.wraps` and MetaClasses:

```
from boltons.funcutils import wraps
# from functools import wraps
from inspect import getfullargspec

def wrap_if_result_signature_desired(self, super, item):
    if item in ['square']:
        return self._signature_wrapper(super.__getattribute__(item))
    return super.__getattribute__(item)

class WrappingMetaClass(type):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return wrap_if_result_signature_desired(self, super(), item)

class A(object, metaclass=WrappingMetaClass):
    def __getattribute__(self, item):        
        return wrap_if_result_signature_desired(self, super(), item)

    @classmethod
    def _signature_wrapper(cls, f):

        @wraps(cls.result)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        wrapper.__name__ = f.__name__
        wrapper.__doc__ = f.__doc__

        return wrapper


    @classmethod
    def result(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod    
    def square(cls, **kwargs):
        r = cls.result(**kwargs)
        return r ** 2   


class B(A):    

    @classmethod
    def result(cls):
        return 2

class C(A):

    @classmethod
    def result(cls, *, x, y):
        return x + y


print(getfullargspec(C.square))
print(getfullargspec(C().square))   


# FullArgSpec(args=['cls'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['x', 'y'], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
# FullArgSpec(args=['cls'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['x', 'y'], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

However, the methods themselves to not work since boltons.funcutils.wraps returns a function rather than a bound method. Hence:

```
#Both do not work
print( C.square(x=1,y=2) )
print( C().square(x=1,y=2) )

#     print( C.square(x=1,y=2) )
# TypeError: result() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
```

NB: using `functools.wraps` works in the sense that the code runs (apparently functools.wraps does bind it to the class), however, it doesn't take over the signature, which is the whole purpose of this exercise in the first place.

Comment: I know of no way to programmatically create a function with a signature defined at runtime in Python. Except for using `compile` or direct AST manipulation, of course, which may be a valid approach if you for some reason want your decorated functions to have specific signatures. Why do you need it? If you explained your bigger problem in more detail, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Just answered with a decorator approach as asked.

Comment: @9000 The base class implements common features of different models, where each model implements the 'result' method differently. We know that the common features will need the same arguments as the 'result' method. If you think a different code design would be more appropriate, I am definitely interested.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
import inspect

def inspect_result_signature(f):
    def inner(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        signature = inspect.getargspec(cls.result)
        print cls.__name__, ':', signature
        return f(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner

class A(object):

    @classmethod
    def result(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    @inspect_result_signature
    def square(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        r = cls.result(*args, **kwargs)
        return r ** 2

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def result(cls):
        return 2

class C(A):

    @classmethod
    def result(cls, x, y):
        return x + y

print B.square()
print C.square(2, 2)
```

Output:

```
$ python signature.py 
<class '__main__.B'> () {}
B : ArgSpec(args=['cls'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
4
<class '__main__.C'> (2, 2) {}
C : ArgSpec(args=['cls', 'x', 'y'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
16
```

For Python3 you have to use `inspect.getfullargspec` or `inspect.signature`

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, this does not solve my problem. Calling `inspect.getfullargspec(C.square)` returns `kwonlyargs=[] ` whereas I would like it to be `kwonlyargs=['x', 'y']`